# Calling Js method on enter button click in asp.net text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal on my aspx page. On this popup, I have a button which has onclick event like this:

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="LoginUsernameTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="login-name" placeholder="Use your email" />

                            <asp:TextBox ID="LoginPasswordTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="login-pass"
                                placeholder="Password (min. 8 chars)" />

<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="LoginPopup();  return false;"
                                CssClass="login-button" Text="<%$ Resources: HRGELoggedOutMaster, Login %>">
                            </asp:Button>
```

This LoginPopup javascript function calls a Webmethod in codebehind like this:

```
  function LoginPopup() {       

        var username = $("#<%= LoginUsernameTextBox.ClientID %>").val();
        var password = $("#<%= LoginPasswordTextBox.ClientID %>").val();     

        if (username != '' && password != '')
            CallPageMethod("LoginPopup", ["username", username, "password", password, "rememberMe", remMe], LoginPopupSucceeded, LoginPopupFailed);
        else
            return false;
    }
```

and CallPageMethod which calls webmethod:

```
 function CallPageMethod(fn, paramArray, successFn, errorFn) {      

        var pagePath = window.location.pathname;
        var Id = getParameterByName('ID');

        //Create list of parameters in the form : {"paramName1":"paramValue1","paramName2":"paramValue2"}
        var paramList = '';
        if (paramArray.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i += 2) {
                if (paramList.length > 0)
                    paramList += ',';
                paramList += '"' + paramArray[i] + '":"' + paramArray[i + 1] + '"';
            }
        }
        paramList = '{' + paramList + '}';
        //Call the page method
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
              url: pagePath + "/" + fn + '?ID=' + Id,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: paramList,
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFn,
            error: function(req, status, err) {
                console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
                alert('something went wrong' + status + err);
            }
        });
    }
```

This all works fine. I have a feature that user can type username and password and click enter button and Login button click function is called. but this always goes to ajax error method as soon as I hit enter. Here is js to fire on click of Login button on popup:

```
$("#<%=this.LoginUsernameTextBox.ClientID%>").keypress(function (event) {     
      fireButtonClick($("#<%=this.btnLogin.ClientID%>"), event);
});

$("#<%=this.LoginPasswordTextBox.ClientID%>").keypress(function (event) {
        fireButtonClick($("#<%=this.btnLogin.ClientID%>"), event);
    });


// default button stuff
function fireButtonClick(ctrl, event) {
    if (event.which || event.keyCode) {
        if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {
            ctrl.click();
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please suggest solution to it.

Comment: What error are you referering to "but this always goes to ajax error method" ?

Comment: are you sure if this url is created properly ? `url: pagePath + "/" + fn + '?ID=' + Id,`

Comment: I am not sure what is the error but I get an alert which is set in ajax error function  error: function(req, status, err) {
                console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
                alert('something went wrong' + status + err);

Comment: So, what is the err value ?

Comment: Use WebInspector and Debug

Comment: @dreamweiver, how can i check this url. I get alert as soon as I hit enter. where as when I click login button using mouse, I go step by step, first in LoginPopup, then in CallPageMethod and then ajaxsucceed.

Comment: no value in err and status = ""

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: one thing, construct this url outside the ajax control and see if this is a valid url, i mostly doubt this is wrong.which u can later pass to `url` parameter

Comment: @dreamweiver, let me try to alert url before ajax call

Comment: @dreamweiver url is same and correct in both cases. It is after servcie method called that ajax error function is called.

Comment: Could you just verify if your receiving the expected data at your server side, you may have to debug your server code manually then, because the ajax call may enter error block on various reason`s and  the reason is hidden in your server code

Comment: How can I know the error details ? I want to get any clue because server side code is working in same flow as it is when user clicks login button

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%=this.LoginUsernameTextBox.ClientID%>").keyup(function (event) {     
      fireButtonClick($(this), event);
});

$("#<%=this.LoginPasswordTextBox.ClientID%>").keyup(function (event) {
        fireButtonClick($(this), event);
    });


// default button stuff
function fireButtonClick(ctrl, event) {
    if (event.which || event.keyCode) {
        if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {
            ctrl.click();
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```